# Pin Row to bottom of Scroll View on top of other UI widgets

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to pin a `Row` container that has a text field input and an adjacent icon button within a `ScrollView`. Unfortunately, the `Row` will stay at the bottom but not with the view of the screen so the user will have to scroll down to see the `Row` container. How can I pin the bottom bar to the screen so that it is always at the bottom within the view of the screen and over the top of the other objects in the `ScrollView`?

Bar UI:

```
class TextBarAtBottom extends StatelessWidget {
  TextEditingController commentController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      // First child is TextInput
      Expanded(
          child: Container(
            child: TextFormField(
              autocorrect: false,
              decoration: new InputDecoration(
                labelText: "Some Text",
                labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black),
                fillColor: Colors.black,
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
              ),
            ),
          )),
      // Second child is button
      IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.send),
        iconSize: 16.0,
        onPressed: () {},
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```

Screen UI:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
        title: 'App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('App'),
            ),
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, children: [
              Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  child: ExpandableTheme(
                      data: ExpandableThemeData(
                          iconColor: Colors.blue,
                          useInkWell: true,
                          animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                          tapBodyToExpand: true,
                          tapHeaderToExpand: true,
                          tapBodyToCollapse: true,
                          hasIcon: true,
                          iconPlacement: ExpandablePanelIconPlacement.right),
                      child: ExpandablePanel(
                          header: Text(widget.postData.title,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
                          collapsed: Text(widget.postData.text,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                              softWrap: true,
                              maxLines: 10,
                              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                          expanded: Text(widget.postData.text,
                              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                              softWrap: true)))),
              // Second child is spacing
              SizedBox(height: 16),
              // Third child is list view of Cards that are populated from the request post
              Flexible(
                  fit: FlexFit.loose,
                  child: Container(
                    child: FutureBuilder<Map<String, String>>(
                      future: post,
                      builder: (context, snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.hasData) {
                          return ListView.builder(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                              itemExtent: 128.0,
                              itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                return Card(Text('$index'));
                              });
                        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                          return Flex(direction: Axis.horizontal, children: [
                            Expanded(
                              child: new Container(),
                            )
                          ]);
                        }
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      },
                    ),
                  )),
              // Fourth child is text bar and send button
              Flexible(fit: FlexFit.loose, child: TextBarAtBottom())
            ]))));
  }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: check my answer

Comment: why don't you try stack widget to make the bottom widget always visible?

Comment: Same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60293414/create-text-input-bar-always-pinned-to-bottom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The results in the screenshot look like this.**

*1. image at the top of the list*

[image: top image]

*2. image at the bottom of the list*

[image: bottom image]
I modified your own code, like this below

```
      MaterialApp(
        title: 'App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Document Thread'),
            ),
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      child: Column(
                          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                          children: [
                            // First child is ExpandableTheme with minHeight of 0.5 screen but expandable to fill up as much screen as needed
                            Flexible(
                              fit: FlexFit.loose,
                              child: ExpandableTheme(
                                  data: ExpandableThemeData(
                                      iconColor: Colors.blue,
                                      useInkWell: true,
                                      animationDuration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                                      tapBodyToExpand: true,
                                      tapHeaderToExpand: true,
                                      tapBodyToCollapse: true,
                                      hasIcon: true,
                                      iconPlacement: ExpandablePanelIconPlacement.right
                                  ),
                                  child: ExpandablePanel(
                                      header: Text('Title',
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24)),
                                      collapsed: Text('Some text',
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                          softWrap: true,
                                          maxLines: 10,
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                                      expanded: Text('widget.postData.docAbstract',
                                          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                          softWrap: true)
                                  )
                              ),
                            ),
                            // Second child is spacing
                            SizedBox(height: 16),
                            // Third child is max height of 0.5 screen with ListView of Card objects or Empty container
                            Flexible(
                              fit: FlexFit.loose,
                              child: Container(
                                //this is limiting your list not to scroll to the bottom
//                        constraints: BoxConstraints(
//                          minWidth: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
//                          maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 2,
//                        ),
                                child: ListView.builder(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  itemCount: 15,
                                  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                                  itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                                    return Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        Padding(
                                          padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(90,0,0,10),
                                          child: Text('Text $index'),
                                        ),
                                        Row(
                                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                          children: <Widget>[
                                            IconButton(
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_up, color: Colors.green,),
                                              onPressed: (){},
                                            ),
                                            IconButton(
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.thumb_down, color: Colors.red,),
                                              onPressed: (){},
                                            )
                                          ],
                                        ),
                                        Divider(color: Colors.black12,)
                                      ],
                                    );
                                   },

                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                            // Fourth child is text bar and send button
                          ]
                      )
                  ),
                ),
                TextBarAtBottom()

              ],
            )
        )
      );
```

Comment: You're pretty close. I'm attempting to get the `TextBarAtBottom` to always be on top like the second screenshot so the user is able to type straight away into the text field

Comment: @black ' so the user will have to scroll down to see the Row container' you said this I modified it based on it. So with your comment now you want the text field visible at all times? from the code I modified I appreciate it if you tell specifically what needs to be changed.

Comment: I added some more code to help. I don't believe it is the `BoxConstraint` that caused the issue but the use of the `ListView` of `Card`s being produced by the `FutureBuilder`

Comment: @Black when you update the code what results did you get?

Comment: An identical screenshot to the one I originally posted

Comment: please can you be more clear on what you want then? Now the text field comes after the user scrolled down. Should I make the text field visible regardless of user scrolling or not? List down the things you want working and let me try my best.

Comment: Yes, so the aim is to have the bottom bar visible regardless of scrolling

Comment: hey @Black check out the updated code and screenshots. Now bottom bar is always visible.

Comment: thank you. Didn't know it would be so simple as adding an extra Column

Answer (score 4):

[image: OutPut Screenshot]

Check my code, it's having textfield at the bottom, and scrollview in the center.

**Problem with your code is** you are adding Textfield inside scrollview so always at the end of SingleChildScrollview.

**Solution:**
Add your SingleChildScrollView inside column view with Expanded widget. and add your Textfield as the second child to Column widget.
Now TextField will be at the bottom and the rest of the space will be taken by SingleChildScrollView.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    class Design extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
     _DesignState createState() => _DesignState();
    }

    class _DesignState extends State<Design> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('TextField at Bottom'),
        ),
          body: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                child: SingleChildScrollView(
                   child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                    Text('Flutter'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Row(children: [
            // First child is TextInput
            Expanded(
                child: Container(
              child: TextFormField(
                autocorrect: false,
                decoration: new InputDecoration(
                  labelText: "Some Text",
                  labelStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, color: Colors.black),
                  fillColor: Colors.black,
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.black)),
                ),
              ),
            )),
            // Second child is button
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.send),
              iconSize: 16.0,
              onPressed: () {},
            )
          ])
        ],
      ),
    );
    }
   }
```

Comment: Please see the screenshot I see from my emulator in the edit